# Ошибка запуска приложении Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, flutter, mobile-development

Когда я запускаю эмулятор андройда с версией 33, выдает следующее:

```
PS C:\Users\1\Documents\flutterProject\myapp> flutter run          
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics 
artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\1\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\1\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit 
value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             30,6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

А flutter doctor:

```
PS C:\Users\1\Documents\flutterProject\myapp> flutter doctor
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on Windows, locale ru-RU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.
HTTP Host availability check is taking a long time...[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while 
checking the HTTP host: Превышен таймаут       
     семафора.


! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Но когда я включу VPN, flutter doctor выдаст мне следующее:

```
PS C:\Users\1\Documents\flutterProject\myapp> flutter doctor
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on Windows, locale ru-RU)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Все это запускаю через VS Code. Я пробовал все методы (Сделал Pub Get|Packages Get, пробовал  ./gradlew clean и ./gradlew build, flutter clean и flutter run, удалил pubspec.lock и
сделал flutter pub get, пробовал flutter channel stable, удалил android studio и flutter а потом переустановил) для исправление этой ошибки, и когда я запускал приложение через эмулятор всегда включил VPN.

Да еще когда я просто сделаю flutter build appbundle выдает тоже самое, но только не ":app:compileFlutterBuildDebug" а ":app:compileFlutterRelease".

Пожалуйста помогите мне решить эту проблему, так как я уже ищу ответ 7-8 дней.
Пригодиться любое решение!

Comment: А вы в какой стране проживаете? Если в России, тогда может быть из-за этого сайт как раз таки и  не пускает вас.

Comment: Я живу в Казахстане.

Comment: Возможно тут вина провайдера. Судя по запросу, ошибке HTTP запроса на `https://pub.dev`, сам запрос был искажён. Возможно не провайдер виноват, а на вас пытались сделать атаку, но это уже мало вероятный случай.

Comment: И что мне делать то?

Comment: использовать VPN, что же ещё остаётся делать.